# Codename One App killed on iOS only (by jetsam reason per-process-limit), randomly

Tags: codenameone

*This question is relevant for Codename One only.*

I recently discovered that the app I'm developing is killed on iOS only, randomly after some minutes of usage.

I copy at the bottom two relevant native logs. "Startpoint" is the main class name. The app is `killed by jetsam reason per-process-limit`. In the log it's written: `StartPoint[11699] exceeded mem limit: ActiveHard 1800 MB (fatal)`. From my point of view, "1800 MB" doesn't make sense: I don't guess how I can use so much memory (currently without videos or images). Is it RAM memory, not Storage memory, right?

Do you think that it could be a problem of the memory management of Codename One on iOS (for example after one of the last commits), or a problem of my coding? I don't know what to do. The same app works fine on Android (tested for two hours).

I have a lot of very long PropertyBusinessObjects. I don't know if it is the cause of the issue, however, after similar user interaction, Android reports a maximum usage of memory equals to 132MB.

Thank you for any help

An example of killing:

```
default 07:47:02.901082 -0700   StartPoint  [EDT] 0:1:35,74 - DB.saveUserDB executing

default 07:47:03.146305 -0700   StartPoint  Received memory warning.

default 07:47:03.375561 -0700   StartPoint  Received memory warning.

default 07:47:03.660729 -0700   kernel  EXC_RESOURCE -> StartPoint[11699] exceeded mem limit: ActiveHard 1800 MB (fatal)

default 07:47:03.660829 -0700   kernel  145148.203 memorystatus: killing_specific_process pid 11699 [StartPoint] (per-process-limit 10) - memorystatus_available_pages: 17916

default 07:47:03.664596 -0700   backboardd  Connection removed: IOHIDEventSystemConnection uuid:CAD772F4-898E-4820-A12C-72F566AB61F3 pid:11699 process:StartPoint type:Monitor entitlements:0x0 caller:GameController: _GCHIDEventCallback + 92 attributes:(null) inactive:0

default 07:47:03.664768 -0700   backboardd  Connection removed: IOHIDEventSystemConnection uuid:A11FAB5D-3EC9-4F42-A047-FF4A85D7BF79 pid:11699 process:StartPoint type:Passive entitlements:0x0 caller:BackBoardServices: <redacted> + 364 attributes:<CFBasicHash 0x102f08b90 [0x102f00010]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,

entries =>

    0 : <CFString 0x1029a2200 [0x1fa609420]>{contents = "pid"} = <CFNumber 0xe083bec570058adf [0x1fa609420]>{value = +11699, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}

    1 : <CFString 0x102950f20 [0x1fa609420]>{contents = "bundleID"} = <CFString 0x1029509e0 [0x1fa609420]>{contents = "com.myapp.apps.frontend"}

    2 : <CFString 0x102930530 [0x1fa609420]>{contents = "HighFrequency"} = <CFBoolean 0x1fa60efd0 [0x1fa609420]>{value = true}

}

 inactive:0

default 07:47:03.681277 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:11699] Setting jetsam priority to 3 [0x100]

errore  07:47:03.681445 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:11699] SyscallError: setpriority(PRIO_DARWIN_ROLE, 11699, 3): No such process

default 07:47:03.682872 -0700   ReportCrash Process StartPoint [11699] killed by jetsam reason per-process-limit

default 07:47:03.948472 -0700   ReportCrash Formulating report for corpse[11699] StartPoint

default 07:47:04.256708 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:11699] Port death watcher fired.

default 07:47:04.257778 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:11699] Ignoring assertion remove, because we are terminated or pending termination

default 07:47:04.258416 -0700   assertiond  Process exited: <BKProcess: 0x103f0a300; StartPoint; com.myapp.apps.frontend; pid: 11699; agency: Application; visibility: none; task: none; hostpid: 55>

default 07:47:04.258489 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:11699] Invalidating...

default 07:47:04.453691 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:11699] Got exit context: <BKSProcessExitContext: 0x102514c00; reason: jetsam>

default 07:47:04.455538 -0700   SpringBoard <FBApplicationProcess: 0x11c4528b0; StartPoint (com.myapp.apps.frontend); pid: 11699> assertiond says the process actually exited with context: <BKSProcessExitContext: 0x283d69270; reason: jetsam>

default 07:47:04.455956 -0700   SpringBoard <FBApplicationProcess: 0x11c4528b0; StartPoint (com.myapp.apps.frontend); pid: 11699> was killed by jetsam.

default 07:47:04.458961 -0700   SpringBoard Removing: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x11c4528b0; StartPoint (com.myapp.apps.frontend); pid: 11699>

default 07:47:04.459919 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:11699] Deleted launchd job with label: UIKitApplication:com.myapp.apps.frontend[0x17dd][65]

default 07:47:04.460764 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:11699] Invalidation complete.

default 07:47:04.461194 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:11699] Terminating because the job-submitter has disconnected.

default 07:47:04.462656 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:11699] Removing client: <BKProcessInfoServerClient: 0x102506990; pid: 55>

default 07:47:04.463201 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:11699] No clients remain.

default 07:47:04.472853 -0700   SpringBoard Process exited: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x11c4528b0; StartPoint (com.myapp.apps.frontend); pid: -1> -> <FBApplicationProcessExitContext: 0x28324d7d0; exitReason: jetsam; terminationReason: (none)> {

    stateAtExit = <FBProcessState: 0x283936a80; pid: 11699; taskState: Not Running; visibility: Unknown>;

}
```

Another example of killing:

```
default 09:07:18.773629 -0700   StartPoint  [EDT] 0:0:37,680 - OverflowMenuUtilities.addCenteredOverflowMenu called

default 09:07:18.863149 -0700   StartPoint  Received memory warning.

default 09:07:18.867041 -0700   StartPoint  Received memory warning.

default 09:07:19.006687 -0700   StartPoint  Received memory warning.

default 09:07:19.072788 -0700   kernel  EXC_RESOURCE -> StartPoint[12051] exceeded mem limit: ActiveHard 1800 MB (fatal)

default 09:07:19.072849 -0700   kernel  149963.662 memorystatus: killing_specific_process pid 12051 [StartPoint] (per-process-limit 10) - memorystatus_available_pages: 18153

default 09:07:19.073576 -0700   backboardd  Connection removed: IOHIDEventSystemConnection uuid:3E721803-095C-4E39-901D-C2C0DE608305 pid:12051 process:StartPoint type:Passive entitlements:0x0 caller:BackBoardServices: <redacted> + 364 attributes:<CFBasicHash 0x108b0d0f0 [0x102f00010]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,

entries =>

    0 : <CFString 0x102942610 [0x1fa609420]>{contents = "pid"} = <CFNumber 0xe083bec57005a0df [0x1fa609420]>{value = +12051, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}

    1 : <CFString 0x102961420 [0x1fa609420]>{contents = "bundleID"} = <CFString 0x102966bc0 [0x1fa609420]>{contents = "cool.teammate.apps.frontend"}

    2 : <CFString 0x10298e5e0 [0x1fa609420]>{contents = "HighFrequency"} = <CFBoolean 0x1fa60efd0 [0x1fa609420]>{value = true}

}

 inactive:0

default 09:07:19.073641 -0700   backboardd  Connection removed: IOHIDEventSystemConnection uuid:C4A07120-9133-46DD-8A7D-2F7D862778C4 pid:12051 process:StartPoint type:Monitor entitlements:0x0 caller:GameController: _GCHIDEventCallback + 92 attributes:(null) inactive:0

default 09:07:19.075535 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:12051] Setting jetsam priority to 3 [0x100]

errore  09:07:19.075703 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:12051] SyscallError: setpriority(PRIO_DARWIN_ROLE, 12051, 3): No such process

default 09:07:19.082126 -0700   ReportCrash Process StartPoint [12051] killed by jetsam reason per-process-limit

default 09:07:19.244289 -0700   ReportCrash Formulating report for corpse[12051] StartPoint

default 09:07:19.624534 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:12051] Port death watcher fired.

default 09:07:19.625654 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:12051] Ignoring assertion remove, because we are terminated or pending termination

default 09:07:19.626144 -0700   assertiond  Process exited: <BKProcess: 0x103f01dc0; StartPoint; cool.teammate.apps.frontend; pid: 12051; agency: Application; visibility: none; task: none; hostpid: 55>

default 09:07:19.626203 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:12051] Invalidating...

default 09:07:19.823911 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:12051] Got exit context: <BKSProcessExitContext: 0x102614310; reason: jetsam>

default 09:07:19.825295 -0700   SpringBoard <FBApplicationProcess: 0x117e383b0; StartPoint (cool.teammate.apps.frontend); pid: 12051> assertiond says the process actually exited with context: <BKSProcessExitContext: 0x283d1bdd0; reason: jetsam>

default 09:07:19.825690 -0700   SpringBoard <FBApplicationProcess: 0x117e383b0; StartPoint (cool.teammate.apps.frontend); pid: 12051> was killed by jetsam.

default 09:07:19.826643 -0700   SpringBoard Removing: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x117e383b0; StartPoint (cool.teammate.apps.frontend); pid: 12051>

default 09:07:19.829529 -0700   SpringBoard Process exited: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x117e383b0; StartPoint (cool.teammate.apps.frontend); pid: -1> -> <FBApplicationProcessExitContext: 0x283339470; exitReason: jetsam; terminationReason: (none)> {

    stateAtExit = <FBProcessState: 0x283f6b2c0; pid: 12051; taskState: Not Running; visibility: Unknown>;

}

default 09:07:19.829932 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:12051] Terminating because the job-submitter has disconnected.

default 09:07:19.835718 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:12051] Deleted launchd job with label: UIKitApplication:cool.teammate.apps.frontend[0xdcc8][65]

default 09:07:19.835853 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:12051] Invalidation complete.

default 09:07:19.836169 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:12051] Removing client: <BKProcessInfoServerClient: 0x102421ef0; pid: 55>

default 09:07:19.836423 -0700   assertiond  [StartPoint:12051] No clients remain.
```

Comment: 1.8gb does seem like a lot for a few minutes of runtime. Did you run the app with a memory profiler to see allocations/GC?  If you can isolate a test case that reproduces this we can debug that on xcode.

Comment: I found that the main cause of the bug is the implementation of `PropertyIndex().loadJSON(...)`. I prepared a test case: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2864

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani Which device(s) did you use in testing and reported this crash?

Comment: IPhone X, iOS version of Jun 2019, I don’t remember which version